# Permutations in $S_5$ commuting with (123)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I know that $\tau \circ \sigma \circ \tau^{-1} = (\tau(1) \tau(2) \tau(3))$ for $\sigma = (123)$ but I don't know how to deduce everything that commutes with $(123)$ in $S_5$. Any hints/tips/solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include what you've tried using an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\tau\circ\sigma=(\tau(1)\tau(2)\tau(3))\circ\tau\tag{1}$$ so it's enough to find all $\tau$ such that $(\tau(1)\tau(2)\tau(3))=(123)$. This gives the values of $\tau$ on the domain $\{1,2,3\}$, leaving $4,5$ free.

Comment: I've tried to work through the problem but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right could you provide the solution?

Comment: Either $\tau(1)=1, \tau(2)=2, \tau(3)=3$; $\tau(1)=2, \tau(2)=3, \tau(3)=1$; or $\tau(1)=3, \tau(2)=1, \tau(3)=2$. Do you see why?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer once you understand it, @math.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand it now but I have six commuting permutations, namely $\{e, (23), (12), (123), (132), (13)\}$ is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct.

Comment: See my comment that starts with "Either". Don't forget $4,5$.

Comment: So how do we prove there are only these three solutions?

Comment: There are six solutions. Don't forget $4$ & $5$.

Comment: They are the only solutions because of equation $(1)$.

Comment: So are the six solutions the three above with either $(45)$ or $(4)(5)$ at the end?

Comment: Yes, that's it.